# Replacing sidekiq jobs with Elixir: how can I learn about concurrency?

Tags: ruby, elixir, sidekiq

I have two workers currently plowing through spikes of thousands and thousands of jobs which essentially amount to "open a telnet connection, send some data, read some data, close"

I've been exploring Elixir and I'm rebuilding an app I know and understand.

How can I find out how many simultaneous "jobs" (think: elixir functions returning a boolean) can I spin up at the same time?

In fact, how many open ports are possible on, say, Ubuntu?

Comment: The number of simultaneous jobs depends on a couple different things. How many cores does your CPU have? How much time is spent waiting on IO to happen? This is just something you are going to need to test and find the sweet spot. In general, you can spawn millions of process in Erlang/Elixir. Best approach would be to spin up a pool of workers. Maybe look at poolboy?

Comment: Poolboy is alright, but you'll need more that that to actually manage the queues of events. I would definitely recommend Flow (or GenStage if you need finer control of what exactly each stage does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some numbers in [Erlang Efficiency Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html).

Specifically,

> The maximum number of simultaneously alive Erlang processes is by
>   default 262,144. This limit can be configured at startup. For more
>   information, see the +P command-line flag in the erl(1) manual page in
>   ERTS.

and

> The maximum number of simultaneously open Erlang ports is often by
>   default 16,384. This limit can be configured at startup. For more
>   information, see the +Q command-line flag in the erl(1) manual page in
>   ERTS.

Of course, these numbers may not be directly relevant depending on your system's design. As @Justin Wood mentioned you should have some kind of task pipeline in place.

Also, take a look at [exq](https://github.com/akira/exq) which is a Job processing library for Elixir, compatible with Sidekiq. It might make your implementation simpler.